# Is it possible to prove (programmatically) that two LINQ queries are equal?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, expression-trees

Let's say there are 2 equivalent queries like

```
var q1 = from x in list select x;
var q2 = from x in list where 1 > 0 select x;
```

Is it possible to prove that they produce the same result set?

E.g. is it possible to  implement a method like

```
static bool AreEqual<T>(IQueryable<T> q1, IQueryable<T> q2) { .. }
```

using the underlying expression tree and so forth?

(My real-life situation is a gigantic, complex query that I'm trying to refactor without breaking)

Comment: The 2 example queries you gave are fundamentally different.  Comparing expression trees wouldn't help, nor would comparing the resultant SQL.  The only way to know for sure is to run both queries and compare the results.  You'll have to test the heck out of it because changes to the clauses can introduce subtle differences.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, especially with Linq-To-SQL.

You could go down to the level of comparing the sql statements, but the resulting SQL might express the same fundamental query in different ways.

The only thing you can do is write test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 var result= q1.Equals(q2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not by comparing the queries themselves, no. Because writing the same query in a different manner will result in different expression trees and resultant SQL.

What you will have to do is run the old query and store the result set in a List. Then run the second query and store the result in a List. You will then have to compare the two Lists and see whether they're identical.

Something like this should work for you:

```
var dif = result1.Except(result2).Count() == 0 && result2.Except(result1).Count() == 0;
```

If dif is False, the two collections are different. We have to Except both ways otherwise if result 2 is longer than result1, you'd get a false match.